# What are the properties of square-matrix algebra with this equivalence class?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices

Consider the set of all square matrices with the following equivalence class:

$\mathbf{A}\sim\mathbf{A}\otimes\mathbf{I}_n$ (or, alternatively, as user @M.G. proposed, $\mathbf{A}\sim\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{A}$, in which case we retain the property $A \sim \operatorname{diag}(A,A,\dots,A)$, but otherwise the systems are isomorphic),

for each $n$, where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product and $\mathbf{I}_n$ is identity matrix of order $n$.

For instance, the following matrices are considered equivalent:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This rule allows to make dot product of any two square matrices irrespectively of their orders,for instance:

$$\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} \cdot \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}=\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}  1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\  3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ \end{array} \right)\cdot\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}  1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\  4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\  0 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 6 \\  7 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\  0 & 7 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 9 \\ \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}  1 & 8 & 2 & 10 & 3 & 12 \\  14 & 1 & 16 & 2 & 18 & 3 \\  4 & 14 & 5 & 16 & 6 & 18 \\  3 & 16 & 6 & 20 & 9 & 24 \\  28 & 3 & 32 & 6 & 36 & 9 \\  12 & 28 & 15 & 32 & 18 & 36 \\ \end{array} \right)$$

The order of the result is the least common multiple of the orders of the original matrices.

We can also define exponentiation of matrices of different order:

$$A^B=\exp( \ln A \cdot B)$$

I wonder, what properties the resulting infinite-dimensional vector space has? Obviously it includes subsets isomorphic to all possible hypercomplex systems, including quaternions, split-quaternions, tessarines, grassman numbers, triplex numbers, $\mathbb{R}^n$, hyperbolic numbers, Clifford algebras and all possible their combinations, allowing to make arithmetic operations on hypercomplex numbers from different systems and mix them in one expression.

But what would be the overall algebraic outlook of this set?

```
Below is the code for Mathematica system that realises this algebra:
Clear["Global`*"];
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
Hold[MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_], StandardForm] ^:= 
    Block[{Internal`$ConvertForms = {}}, 
     TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[MatrixForm@a][[1, 1, 3]]}, "Matrix", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{style@"(", "\[NoBreak]", #, 
           "\[NoBreak]", style@")"} &)]]] /. 
  style[string_] -> StyleBox[string, FontColor -> Red] // ReleaseHold
Matrix /: Plus[Matrix[A_?SquareMatrixQ], Matrix[B_?SquareMatrixQ]] := 
 Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] + 
   KroneckerProduct[B, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]]
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[A_?SquareMatrixQ], Matrix[B_?SquareMatrixQ]] := 
 Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
   KroneckerProduct[B, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]]
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Log[Matrix[x]] . Matrix[y]];
Matrix /: Log[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
 Log[Matrix[x]]^-1 . Log[Matrix[y]]
$Post2 = 
  FullSimplify[# /. 
      f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
       Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]] /. 
     NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot] &;
$Post = Nest[$Post2, #, 3] /. Dot -> NonCommutativeMultiply &;
```

Test:

```
Matrix[{
   {1, 3},
   {0, 2}
  }]^Matrix[{
   {1, 0, 1},
   {1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 2}
  }]
```

Comment: [Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4596800/29335) from math.se

Comment: Even more canonically, you can consider the obvious diagonal inclusions $\operatorname{M}_m(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$ for $m|n$ and take $\operatorname{colim} \operatorname{M}_m(\mathbb{R})$, the colimit over this diagram. This gives you an (infinite-dimensional) algebra containing all those "number systems" interacting with each other. Then you may also want to complete this infinite-dimensional algebra.

Comment: @M.G. I am sorry, I am not familiar with your notation. What does $m|n$ mean? What is colimit? Can you please give an example?

Comment: $m|n$ simply means $m$ dividing $n$. For the second I refer you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit. I would suggest that you try and work out the equivalence relation to see how different matrices identify with each other. Simplest non-trivial case would be the diagonal embeddings of $\operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ into $\operatorname{M}_6(\mathbb{R})$ to see which 2x2 matrices can be identified with which 3x3 matrices (because their images will be the same). I don't have time now to tex (rather big) matrices.

Comment: @M.G. so, your point is that there is a natural generalization of this proposed equivalence class in which there are equivalent $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ matrices which are not scalar matrices? Did I understand it correctly? My current impression, there are none...

Comment: @M.G. Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge of category theory and cannot digest the linked article.

Comment: @Anixx: No, you are correct that only scalar matrices get identified this way. My point was that you still get a very big algebra, in which all these "number systems" are contained and hence interact with each other. Your construction is different, it's about taking tensor products of matrix algebras. Which is why I only left a comment, that's all.

Comment: @M.G. so, do you propose another equivalence relation, which makes the algebra a bit "smaller"?

Comment: @Anixx: no, not really, they are both going to be infinite-dimensional, since in the end you want to make identifications for square matrices of every size. This is just a different way to obtain a union of all "number systems".

Comment: When I said "only scalar matrices get identified this way", I meant of course "aside from other matrices that are already diagonal block matrices". But, yes, in the case 2 and 3 into 6, only scalar matrices.

Comment: @M.G. can you give an example of two matrices which are equivalent in your proposed equivalence relation but not in the equivalence class from the OP? Is your equivalence class more "exonomic" in that it allows to multiply matrices to get matrices of less order than LCM of the orders of original matrices?

Comment: @Anixx: Yes, for example $A$ and $\operatorname{diag}(A,A)$ would be equivalent in the second case, but they won't be equivalent in your case as your own example shows. I don't know if this is desirable or not for you.

It is not possible to get less than LCM b/c of the following lemma: if you have an arbitrary inclusion $\operatorname{M}_m(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$ of matrix algebras, then necessarily $m$ has to divide $n$. This is the case with your construction and it is the case with my construction.

Comment: @M.G. are there equivalent matrices of the same order in your proposal? Eg.like $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & 0 & 0 \\
 b & a & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & a & b \\
 0 & 0 & b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 b & 0 & a & 0 \\
 0 & b & 0 & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$ or it is simply a rule $A=\operatorname{diag}(A,A)$, in the later case it would have roughly the same properties to what I propose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141303/discussion-between-m-g-and-anixx).